Redis crashing after using no root user inside a container
I am writing this to ask about a problem I've been facing lately, after changing the configuration of my redis service from a root user to a non-root user in my container, i've been facing this problem:
12408:C 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.299 # WARNING Memory overcommit must be enabled! Without it, a background save or replication may fail under low memory condition. Being disabled, it can also cause failures without low memory condition, see https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1328. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect. 
12408:C 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.299 * oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo 
12408:C 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.299 * Redis version=7.2.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=12408, just started 
12408:C 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.299 * Configuration loaded 
12408:M 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.300 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime 
12408:M 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.301 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379. 
12408:M 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.301 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128. 
12408:M 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.301 * Server initialized 12408:M 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.301 . The AOF directory appendonlydir doesn't exist 
12408:M 02 Jul 2024 17:01:53.301 # Can't open or create append-only dir appendonlydir: Permission denied

Here's my config
[program:redis-server]

command=redis-server --requirepass foobared --appendonly yes --loglevel debug --logfile path/redis-server.log --stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no --save ""

user=my-user

priority=2

autostart=false

dependent_startup=true

When I tried to remove --appendoly yes, it works, but my problem is that I need to keep it.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve it ?

Might be useful to see the docker, docker compose and/or Dockerfile used to build and run the container.
